# Como imprimir/plotar uma tabela no #R?

Tags: r

Considere:

```
 dat <-  matrix(c(1000, 100, 10000, 10000,3.145,1700.42), 2)
```

Em que `dat` refere-se a dados do resultado de um loop, gerando-se um novo `dat` a cada ciclo. Preciso apresentar estes resultados, para isto, pensei em exportar `dat` para um formato tabular ou uma imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso gerar esta informação/resultado no R como uma tabela já formatada (linhas de margem e cabeçalho) ou imagem, isto é possível?

Comment: Não está claro o que você quer. Você quer plotar num gráfico, como figura, ou imprimir na tela com uma formatação mais amigável?

Comment: Assim que puder vou melhorar a pergunta. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando como referência [essa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558266/r-data-frame-to-table-image-for-presentation), cheguei ao seguinte:

Antes de tudo, avalie bem se você quer mesmo fazer isto. Texto e formatação são muito mais flexíveis e fáceis de modificar que uma imagem.

Uma maneira simples de fazer o que você quer é usar o pacote `gridExtra`:

```
library("gridExtra")

dat <- matrix(c(1000, 100, 10000, 10000,3.145,1700.42), 2)
grid.table(dat)
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tabela ficou sem títulos porque é uma matriz sem `colnames`. Você pode customizar a imagem, mas a sintaxe não é tão simples. Para ver o que pode ser feito, você precisa investigar os valores do tema padrão:

```
> ttheme_default()
$core
$core$fg_fun    
...    
$core$fg_params
$core$fg_params$parse
[1] FALSE
$core$fg_params$col
[1] "black"

$core$fg_params$fontsize
[1] 12
...
```

Você pode personalizar o tema da seguinte forma:

```
mytheme <- ttheme_default()
mytheme$core$bg_params$fill <- c("yellow", "pink")
grid.table(dat, theme = mytheme)
```

Que levaria a este resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se quiser mesmo investir nisso, dê uma olhada no help (`?grid.table`) e no tema padrão para ver o que pode ser modificado.

Comment: Imensamente agradecido!